# How to Handle Sqlite CursorIndexOutOfBound exception

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am accessing data from `SQLiteDatabase` by entering a key in `EditText`. Whenever I enter some wrong key,which is not in the database my application stops. I don't want my application to stop, instead i want to show as toast here.
 How can i do this?

```
  try{

    Log.e("table", table_name);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT  name,address1,address2,address3,tariff,sup_type,load,load_unit,meter_no,pole_cd,mst FROM "+table_name+"  WHERE acc_id = '"+ i +" ' ", null);

        if (c.equals(null)) 
        { 
           c.moveToFirst(); 
           Log.e("c", "i am null"+ c.toString());
        } 
        else if (c!=null) {
            c.moveToNext();
            Log.e("c", "i am notnull" + c.toString());
        }

        return c; 

    } 
    catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
    { 
        Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
        throw mSQLException; 
    }
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace.. Change your if condition to if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()) {... }

Comment: have you tried `c == null` instead of `c.equals(null)` ?

Comment: you can't do `c.moveToFirst();` when cursor is null. so only check `if(c.moveToFirst()){//null}else{//not null}`

Answer (score 1):

Always check Cursor count before using the cursor like

```
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                // your logic goes here
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Record Found", 1000).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use `c == null` instead of `c.equals(null)` because

From doc:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references

...

> for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if
>   and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value
>   true).